# Implementing a simple Java writer plugin for collectd

Tags: java, collectd

I'm trying to develop a very simple Java writer plugin for collectd with no success. Didn't find any documentation for Java plugins development either.

I encounter the same error over and over again, that the class provided in the LoadPlugin element (collectd.config) was not found on the agent startup.

Here’s what I’ve done:

1. Installed collectd using: sudo apt-get install collectd.
2. Downloaded collectd sources.
3. Added a new (very simple) writer plugin under /bindings/java/org/collectd/java.
4. Modified the /bindings/java/Makefile.am:

   - Added the writer to the EXTRA_DIST list
   - Added the following line to the java-build-stamp task (to create a jar for the new writer): jar cf .lib/simple.jar “com.microsoft.java”/*.class
   - Added the following line to the install-exec-local task: $(INSTALL) –m 644 .libs/simple.jar \ “$(DESTDIR)$(pkgdatadir)/java”
5. Executed ./configure from the sources root directory.
6. Executed sudo make all install from bindings/java directory.
7. Modified collectd.config:

   - Enabled the Java plugin
   - Enabled the new plugin by adding: “LoadPlugin “com.microsoft.java.SimpleWriter” to the Java plugin section
   - Update the JVM class path argument to include the jar containing the new plugin.
8. Started collectd by executing: sudo /etc/init.d/collectd start

When I enabled the GenericJMX plugin it has been loaded successfully.
Does anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracting the jar content into the classpath folder solved the problem. It seems that if your class name is com.company.foo.FooClass, CollectD searches it under directory (class_path_dir)/com/company/foo/FooClass.class